# $("#cal").append(message); has errors

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#calBox0").append(message); //calling this id"calBox3",this statesment is right;
```

but now,

```
var cal=calBox0;
$("#cal").append(message); //has errors ;
```

i want to know why?

```
 <tr > //grid  
    <td class="calBox" id="calBox0"></td>  

</tr>
```

Comment: Where is #cal in your html?

Comment: This is not a jquery question. It is a lack of understanding of javascript.

Comment: @Smile can you your full code?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var cal= 'calBox0';

$('#'+cal).append(message);
```

Comment: i tried all, no uses

Comment: thank you for Rohan Kumar、Cattla and 10sw33 , i successed!!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#cal")` here "cal" is a String it self you have to use a variable having value 'calBox0'
so use `$("#"+cal)` instead of `$("#cal")`